# What does this Android mono-rt stack trace mean? (AndHud 1.3.1)

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms, stack-trace

Periodically my Xamarin.Forms Android app crashes with this error, yet 99% of the time the [AndroidHud (AndHud)](https://components.xamarin.com/view/andhud) component renders its dialog with messages as expected.  It's invoked from the UI thread, from my MainActivity (no other activity is active at the time).

```
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) <0x00053>
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment/InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference,Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x0006c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11639
[mono-rt]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (string,Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:26
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.Dialog.SetContentView (Android.Views.View) [0x0002c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Dialog.cs:2160
[mono-rt]   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD/<SetupDialog>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__0 (object) <IL 0x000be, 0x00483>
[mono-rt]   at Android.App.SyncContext.Send (System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:26
[mono-rt]   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD.SetupDialog (Android.Content.Context,AndroidHUD.MaskType,System.Action,System.Func`4<Android.Content.Context, Android.App.Dialog, AndroidHUD.MaskType, Android.Views.View>) <IL 0x0003d, 0x0023f>
[mono-rt]   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD.showStatus (Android.Content.Context,bool,string,AndroidHUD.MaskType,System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>,System.Action,bool,System.Action) <IL 0x000cd, 0x0064f>
[mono-rt]   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Show (Android.Content.Context,string,int,AndroidHUD.MaskType,System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>,System.Action,bool,System.Action) <IL 0x0002c, 0x0021f>
[mono-rt]   at Apollo1.Droid.MainActivity.showProgress (Apollo1.Domain.ProgressEvent) [0x00059] in /Volumes/Devology/Source Code/Agile Orange Ltd/Apollo1.Mobile/Apollo1.Android/MainActivity.cs:254
[mono-rt]   at Apollo1.Droid.MainActivity/<handleProgressEvent>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x000c2] in /Volumes/Devology/Source Code/Agile Orange Ltd/Apollo1.Mobile/Apollo1.Android/MainActivity.cs:241
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
[mono-rt]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/0e59c362/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.3f472f08-eb57-4472-a265-297a4af40e0a (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.3f472f08-eb57-4472-a265-297a4af40e0a (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00021, 0x000ef>
```

This is how I normally initiate the dialog...

```
this.Publish<ProgressEvent>(new ProgressEvent("Lets show this message!"));
```

And this is what listens to that event

```
void handleProgressEvent (ProgressEvent progressEvent)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        // Ensure only one thing can enter at a time
        lock (this) { // <-- Added recently to try to solve the problem
            if (progressEvent.Hide) {
                hideProgress ();
            } else {
                if (currentProgressMessage != null && !progressEvent.Message.Equals (currentProgressMessage)) {
                    // Don't bother hiding if it's the same message about to be shown
                    if (!currentProgressMessage.Equals (progressEvent.Message)) {
                        hideProgress ();
                    }
                }
                // Don't bother showing if it's the same message
                if (!progressEvent.Message.Equals (currentProgressMessage)) {
                    showProgress (progressEvent);
                }

                currentProgressMessage = progressEvent.Message;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The methods that show / hide the dialog were very simply delegates to the component itself, but I've been adding logging and exception handling (which makes no difference - the app still crashes).

```
void showProgress (ProgressEvent progressEvent)
{
    try {
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.INFO, "AndroidHUD invoking show with Forms.Context" + Forms.Context + " progressEvent.Message:" + progressEvent.Message);
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.Show (Forms.Context, progressEvent.Message, -1, AndroidHUD.MaskType.Black);
        showing++;
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.INFO, "AndroidHUD show completed showing:"+showing);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.ERROR, "AndroidHUD show error caught with reason e:" + e.Message);
        logger.Log (this, e);
    }
}

void hideProgress ()
{
    try {
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.INFO, "AndroidHUD invoking hideProgress with Forms.Context" + Forms.Context);
        AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Shared.Dismiss (Forms.Context);
        showing--;
        currentProgressMessage = null;
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.INFO, "AndroidHUD hideProgress completed showing:" + showing);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.Log (this, LogLevelEnum.ERROR, "AndroidHUD hideProgress error caught with reason e:" + e.Message);
        logger.Log (this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It usually is a pretty hard crash. For some reason the AndHUD Show method crashes your app. If you want to show Dialogs cross platform, I recommend using Acr.UserDialogs, it will lead to much cleaner code, than passing messages around.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone elses benefit, I don't believe it was AndHud's fault in the end.

I found some events being fired on their current thread context, rather than on the UI thread. The receiving listeners were performing UI operations.

Since I've made that change, I have not seen this error in days.

It seems that if you don't keep on the UI thread things can break somewhere completely different!